# What needs to be done inorder to change difficulty?

Tags: block, difficulty

I'm trying for a while to reduce difficulty of main network to do some experiments on transactions and maybe simulate some possible attacks.I came up to change nBits field in chainparams.cpp but it seems it is not enough and the new network didn't run properly. What else should I do exactly ?